# Constructor Injection with TinyIoC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor-injection, tinyioc

I have just changed from Ninject to TinyIoC for dependency injection and I'm having trouble with constructor injection.

I have managed to simplify it down to this snippet:

```
public interface IBar { } 

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IBar bar) { }
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public Bar(string value) { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;

        string value = "test";
        container.Register<IBar, Bar>().UsingConstructor(() => new Bar(value));

        var foo = container.Resolve<Foo>();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.GetType());
    }
}
```

which causes a TinyIoCResolutionException to be thrown with:

```
"Unable to resolve type: TinyIoCTestApp.Foo"
```

and inside that exception is a chain of inner exceptions:

```
"Unable to resolve type: TinyIoCTestApp.Bar"
"Unable to resolve type: System.String"
"Unable to resolve type: System.Char[]"
"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: key"
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm using the constructor injection? I realize I could call

```
container.Register<IBar, Bar>(new Bar(value));
```

and that does indeed work, however the result is a global instance of Bar which is not what I'm after.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also: I'm using TinyIoC from Github (https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC)

Comment: Funny, the rationale behind TinyIoC has much in common with that of the [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com).

Comment: @Steven and we're both called Steven too .. spooky :-P

Comment: @Steven: Nothing but good can come out of that ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not familiar with TinyIOC, but I think I can answer your question.

The `UsingConstructor` registers a lambda that points at a constructor (the `ctor(string)`) that TinyIOC will use to do automatic constructor injection into. TinyIOC will analyse the constructor arguments, finds an argument of type `System.String` and tries to resolve that type. Since you haven't registered `System.String` explicitly (which you shouldn't btw), resolving `IBar` (and thus `Foo`) fails.

The incorrect assumption you made is that TinyIOC will execute your `() => new Bar(value))` lambda, which it will not. If you look at the `UsingConstructor` method you will propable see that it takes an `Expression<Func<T>>` instead of a `Func<T>`.

The thing you want, is to register a factory delegate that does the creation. I expect TinyIOC to contain a method for this. It might look something like this:

```
container.Register<IBar>(() => new Bar(value));
```

Comment: Yep, UsingConstructor is a way to select which constructor to use and for 99% of the time isn't necessary. What you want is the Register overload that takes Func<TinyIoCContainer, NamedParameterOverloads, object> and supply a simple factory to return your new Bar.

Comment: I agree. `UsingConstructor` is only useful when your type has multiple constructors, which should in general be avoided when doing DI. I even left a constructor selection feature of of Simple Injector because of that.

Comment: Well, multiple constructors are generally fine with TinyIoC because it takes the "greediest constructor I can successfully resolve" approach, but there are occasions where you want to override that.

Comment: Interesting. I force Simple Injector users to have a single constructor on types that are auto-wired, because of two reasons. First of all, the general advice with DI is to let a type have a single definition of the dependencies it needs. If you have multiple constructors, you have multiple definitions. But second: all containers use a different overload resolution. Some containers are greedy, while others aren't. Forcing users to have a single constructor makes it easier to migrate to another DI framework when needed.

Comment: @Stevens: Whoa, I'm seeing double! :) I changed the `Register` call to use the overload as suggested and all is well now. Thanks guys!

Comment: @AndrewG: Building on what you mentioned, I used `container.Register<IBar, Bar>(new Bar(myParameter));`