# Resolve concrete type with constructor arguments using TinyIoC

Tags: c#, nancy, tinyioc

I have a Nancy API and have created a custom Bootstraper who inherits from `DefaultNancyBootstrapper`.

I also have the concrete type `ConcreteFoo` which i would like to bind to self in request scope and pass a specific constructor argument.

```
public class ConcreteFoo {
    private readonly int _baseInteger;
    public ConcreteFoo(int baseInteger) {
        _baseInteger = baseInteger;
    }
}
```

My custom Bootstraper is the following:

```
public class Bootstraper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper {
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container) {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(TinyIoCContainer container, NancyContext context) {
        base.ConfigureRequestContainer(container, context);
        container.Resolve<ConcreteFoo>(new NamedParameterOverloads {{"baseInteger", 100}});
    }
}
```

In order to resolve `ConcreteFoo` with the desired constructor parameter I have used the example provided in [TinyIoC Wiki](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC/wiki/Resolution---constructor-and-property-injection). I noticed that the code passes from the overrides in my custom bootstraper and if I write the below, the `response` is true.

```
var response = container.CanResolve<ConcreteFoo>(new NamedParameterOverloads {{"baseInteger", 100}});
```

**However, I get an exception** while the application is bootstraping. The inner-inner-inner... (lot's of inner) exception is listed below and states that it cannot create `ConcreteFoo` and that it's unable to resolve `System.Int32`.

```
InnerException: Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Unable to resolve type: TestService.Api.ConcreteFoo
  Source=Nancy
  StackTrace:
       at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
       at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.MultiInstanceFactory.GetObject(Type requestedType, TinyIoCContainer container, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
  InnerException: Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Unable to resolve type: System.Int32
       Source=Nancy
       StackTrace:
            at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
            at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
            at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal(TypeRegistration registration, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202899/constructor-injection-with-tinyioc) relevant question but it refers to registering an interface and not a concrete type.

Am I doing something wrong, or are you familiar with another way to resolve the concrete type and provide the constructor argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need container.Register...

Anyway, lately I prefer to use IRegistration classes, which are auto-wired by Nancy. That way the things are separated by topic/concern, and the bootstrapper is not modified at all.

Comment: I had already tried that and failed. Then I switched to Resolve. However, the real issue came from the fact that in the SetApplicationContainer() I had a Singleton (default for Interfaces) which tried to use the InRequestScope ConcreteFoo. I changed the Singleton to MultiInstance and worked as it should with the Register. Thank you for the help.